How do I get a rolling group by function with a Julia dataframe to work
How do you run a simple group by rolling function in julia? I am having a hard time getting past this code line:
rolling_mean = rolling(rollmean, group_data[!, value_col], window_size)

using DataFrames
using RollingFunctions

# Create an example DataFrame
data = DataFrame(group = repeat(["A", "B"], outer = 5),
                 time = 1:10,
                 value = rand(10) * 100)

# Display the DataFrame
println("Original DataFrame:")
println(data)

# Function to calculate rolling mean for each group
function rolling_group_mean(df::DataFrame, group_col::Symbol, value_col::Symbol, window_size::Int)
    # Create a new DataFrame for results
    result = DataFrame()

    # Loop through each unique group
    for g in unique(df[!, group_col])
        group_data = df[df[!, group_col] .== g, :]

        # Calculate rolling mean and convert to a vector
        rolling_mean = rolling(rollmean, group_data[!, value_col], window_size)

        # Create a DataFrame with the results
        group_result = DataFrame(group = fill(g, length(rolling_mean)),
                                  time = group_data.time,
                                  rolling_mean = rolling_mean)

        # Append results to the result DataFrame
        append!(result, group_result)
    end

    return result
end

# Apply the function
window_size = 3
result_df = rolling_group_mean(data, :group, :value, window_size)

# Display the result
println("Rolling Mean DataFrame:")
println(result_df)

I get the following error:
ERROR: LoadError: BoundsError: attempt to access 0-element Vector{Any} at index [1]
ERROR: LoadError: BoundsError: attempt to access 0-element Vector{Any} at index [1]
Stacktrace:
 [1] getindex
   @ ./essentials.jl:13 [inlined]
 [2] rts
   @ ~/.julia/packages/RollingFunctions/fR9uW/src/support/utils.jl:49 [inlined]
 [3] basic_rolling(window_fn::typeof(rollmean), data1::Vector{Float64}, window_span::Int64)
   @ RollingFunctions ~/.julia/packages/RollingFunctions/fR9uW/src/roll/rollvectors.jl:17
 [4] #rolling#7
   @ ~/.julia/packages/RollingFunctions/fR9uW/src/roll/roll.jl:4 [inlined]
 [5] rolling(window_fn::typeof(rollmean), data1::Vector{Float64}, window_span::Int64)
   @ RollingFunctions ~/.julia/packages/RollingFunctions/fR9uW/src/roll/roll.jl:1
 [6] rolling_group_mean(df::DataFrame, group_col::Symbol, value_col::Symbol, window_size::Int64)
   @ Main 

@GWD almost -- the rolling function now structurally works with the result:
group   time   value    rolling_mean 
String  Int64  Float64  Float64?     
─────────────────────────────────────
A 1  50.032   missing      
A 3  86.4701  missing      
A 5  93.8029 76.7684
A 7  35.4118 71.8949
A 9  76.0579 68.4242
B 2  49.6533  missing      
B 4  96.2246  missing      
B 6  47.4889 64.4556
B 8  59.0001 67.5712
B 10  31.5858 46.0249

Is there a way to get the values for first two rows to equal the average of all data availabe to it at the time of the roll with the window=3? Shown below:
group   time   value    rolling_mean 
String  Int64  Float64  Float64?     
─────────────────────────────────────
A 1  50.032   50.032 <--- avg(just the first row)      
A 3  86.4701  68.251 <--- avg(the first row and second row)           
A 5  93.8029 76.7684
A 7  35.4118 71.8949
A 9  76.0579 68.4242
B 2  49.6533  49.6533 <--- avg(just the first row)      
B 4  96.2246  72.93895  <--- avg(the first row and second row)
B 6  47.4889 64.4556
B 8  59.0001 67.5712
B 10  31.5858 46.0249


Define a Rolling Mean Function with "Padding".
Since applying a rolling mean with a window size will reduce the number of elements, I'd define some helper function to pad the beginning of each group's rolling mean with eg. 'missing' values.
This should ensure that the rolling mean aligns correctly with yr original DataFrame.
...

function rolling_mean_padded(x, window_size)
        mean_vals = rollmean(x, window_size)
        padding_length = window_size - 1
        return vcat(fill(missing, padding_length), mean_vals)
    end
grouped_data = groupby(data, :group)
window_size = 3

result_df= transform(grouped_data, :value => (x -> rolling_mean_padded(x, window_size)) => :rolling_mean) 
println(resutl_df)

Additional comment - in case my result is still "off", of what you're trying to achieve ...
I had a bit of a hard time fully deducing your "expected result".
This could be mitigated if you'd include the expected result_df (eg. fixing the rand seed and constructing the result_df "by hand" or just using non-random numbers and calculating the desired window rolling mean "by hand" and presenting the "result_df" here as well).
Otherwise - hope this fits the problem.

Almost there; I posted a follow up question essentially I want to calculate the rolling mean over 3 time periods even if there is less than 3 time periods worth of data.
Example in python pandas:
group.rolling(window, on='CHARTTIME_WINDOW', min_periods=1)['SIGNAL_VALUE'].mean()
